# jquery, add/remove class to list item when window width changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to add a class to my list items if they have a sub ul but only at a specific window width:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="hassub">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li> 
</ul>
```

I found two working jsfiddles and tried to combine them.
This is what I got: https://jsfiddle.net/Flouks/413qdd63/

These are the two I try to combine:

1: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/1/

2: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/1/

Thanks in advance for your help.

(*Note to myself: learn jquery*)

Comment: You just have to add jQuery to jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/azp4n94h/1/ - In the left panel in the Frameworks drowndown select jQuery version

Comment: Almost every question I ask here, I regret sooner or later. The answers are always so simple. Thanks @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add JQuery to the JSFiddle.

[Here is a link to the update one](https://jsfiddle.net/413qdd63/1/)

Your code does add and remove the class as intended.

```
if ($window.width() < 500) {
            return $bla.addClass('hassub');
        }
    $bla.removeClass('hassub');
```